# What would be the distribution of $S_1+S_2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Note : For details about the Wishart distribution $\mathcal W_p(\Sigma,n)$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution).

Let $S_1\sim \mathcal{W}_p(\Sigma_1,n_1)$ and $S_2\sim \mathcal{W}_p(\Sigma_2,n_2)$

I know that if for example we have the case that $\Sigma_1=\Sigma=\Sigma_2$, then $S_1+S_2\sim \mathcal{W}_p(\Sigma,n_1+n_2)$

But what if for example $\Sigma_1=\frac{n_1-1}{n_1}\Sigma$ and $\Sigma_2=\frac{n_2-1}{n_2}\Sigma$

What would be the distribution of $S_1+S_2$?

Comment: Because $B_d(x,1)$ is not necessarily the same as $B_{d_1}(x,1)$.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what does $\mathcal{W}_p$ stand for?

Comment: @Arash Wishart distribution!

Comment: I have edited the question to include the Wikipedia page for the Wishart distribution, since it is a slightly less known distribution than the other usual ones. You can reject this edit if you feel it is not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are independent, then I think this paper can provide the answer you are looking for: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6638.pdf. Specifically equations (10) and (11). The expression involves hypergeometric functions.